# Django Upload form to S3 img and form validation

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I'm fairly new to both Django and Python. This is my first time using forms and upload files with django. I can get the uploads and saves to the database to work fine but it fails to valid email or check if the users selected a file to upload. I've spent a lot of time reading documentation trying to figure this out. Thanks!

views.py

```
def submit_photo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        def store_in_s3(filename, content):
            conn = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
            bucket = conn.create_bucket(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
            mime = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0] 
            k = Key(bucket)
            k.key = filename
            k.set_metadata("Content-Type", mime)
            k.set_contents_from_file(content)
            k.set_acl('public-read')

        if imghdr.what(request.FILES['image_url']):
            qw = request.FILES['image_url']
            filename = qw.name
            image = filename
            content = qw.file
            url  = "http://bpd-public.s3.amazonaws.com/" + image

            data = {image_url : url, user_email : request.POST['user_email'], user_twittername : request.POST['user_twittername'], user_website : request.POST['user_website'], user_desc : request.POST['user_desc']}
            s = BeerPhotos(data)
            if s.is_valid():
                #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                s.save()
                store_in_s3(filename, content)      
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('photos.views.thanks'))
            return s.errors
        else:           
            return errors

    else:
        form = BeerPhotoForm()

    return render_to_response('photos/submit_photos.html', locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

forms.py

```
class BeerPhotoForm(forms.Form):
    image_url = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput, required=True,label='Beer',help_text='Select a image of no more than 2MB.')
    user_email = forms.EmailField(required=True,help_text='Please type a valid e-mail address.')
    user_twittername = forms.CharField()
    user_website = forms.URLField(max_length=128,)
    user_desc = forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.Textarea,label='Description',)
```

template.html

```
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
    <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" width="450px">
        <h1>Photo Submission</h1>
        {% for field in form %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
        <label><span>Click here</span></label>      
    <input type="submit" class="greenbutton" value="Submit your Photo" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Giving up on this for now. Uploading locally and will figure it out in the future thats for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using a `forms.ImageField()` to validate a url. You may want to be using `forms.UrlField()`.

Or

You should not be passing around the url to the file at all. Instead you could be doing `s = BeerPhoto(request.POST, request.FILES)` and process the file after you run `s.is_valid()`

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: I'm only saving the URL in the database and the image is uploaded to s3. I've moved imghr check so its done after the s.is_valid(). Thanks for the suggestions so far. It's not working yet.